# How to model quadratic equation using a bezier curve (calculate control point)

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, bezier

I am making a projectile motion simulation using canvas and I need to draw the line of the projectile's path (trajectory). I believe the best way to do this would be to draw a bezier curve using the quadraticCurveTo() method to accomplish this (since projectile motion can be modeled with a parabola).

I know the start and end points of the parabola along with the max value, but I am not sure how I would go about calculating the control point for my bezier curve.

Comment: actually, Beziers are utterly horrible for projectile trajectories, as the time parameter isn't linear with distance. For projectiles you just want to use the far simpler, and correct-wrt-physics parabolic function.

Comment: What is correct-wrt-physics parabolic function?

Comment: "correct with respect to physics". Object trajectories typically follow a parabolic path, which is y expressed in terms of x. It's relatively easy to draw a parabolic function using Bezier curves, but you don't want to use the Bezier for anything other than purely drawing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are more accurate ways to calculate a quadratic control point, but this close approximation has the benefit of being very quick to calculate:

```
// calc a control point
var cpX = 2*anywhereOnCurveX -startX/2 -endX/2;
var cpY = 2*anywhereOnCurveY -startY/2 -endY/2;
```

Here's a live demo which calculates the approximate control point given a starting point, ending point and any point on the curve (any point other than the start/end point):

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6jNCM/

Comment: How much of an "approximation" is this?

Comment: This calculation is based on interval T=0.50, so if you provide the starting, ending and midpoint of the curve the calculation will be perfect.  This seems best for your needs where you're firing a projectile from A to B and you have the apex point. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

For a Bezier curve to form a parabola, the second derivative must be constant. This requires: P0 - 3 * P1 = P3 - 3 * P2.

The following control points can be used:

```
P0 = (x - w, y)
P1 = (x - w/3, y + h)
P2 = (x + w/3, y + h)
P3 = (x + w, y)
```

Comment: What are `h` and `w`?

Answer (score 0):

More accurate version to draw the parabola (with given a, b, c parameters) wit Bezier curve (solution with Lua for Love2D, but you can read the code):

```
function drawBezierParabola (a, b, c, y1, y2)
    -- crop points:
    local x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*(c-y1))) / (2*a)
    local x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*(c-y2))) / (2*a)
    
    --[[ or by given x1 and x2:
    local y1 = a * x1^2 + b * x1 + c
    local y2 = a * x2^2 + b * x2 + c
    ]]

    -- derivatives:
    local k1 = 2 * a * x1 + b
    local k2 = 2 * a * x2 + b

    -- bezier control point:
    local xi = -b/(2*a) - (y2 - y1) / (k1 - k2)
    local yi = k1 * (xi - x1) + y1

    local bezier = love.math.newBezierCurve (x1, y1, xi, yi, x2, y2)
    love.graphics.line (bezier:render())
end
```